# COMO PUEDO ACTUALIZAR DATOS DE UNA TABLA ORACLE SQL DESDE JAVA

Tags: java, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, update

he estado intentando actualizar datos de una tabla desde java pero mi código marca error, tengo dos versiones de código una lanza una excepción de SQL y la otra no, pero solo me tira un null.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el ejemplo de mi formulario

```
   try {
    main miconexion = new main();
    miconexion.conn=main.Enlace(conn);
    String cve, nom, apa, ama , dep;
cve=  txtcEmpleado.getText();
nom=  txtNombre.getText();
apa= txtApaterno.getText();
ama= txtAmaterno.getText();
dep= txtDepartamento.getText();        
       String sqlactualizar="UPDATE empleados SET nombre="+nom+",apPaterno="+apa+",apMaterno="+ama+",departamento="+dep+" WHERE cuentaEmpleado="+cve+")";
       PreparedStatement psta=conn.prepareStatement(sqlactualizar);
        psta.execute();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empleado Actualizado Satisfactoriamente");
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getCause());

    }
```

El código de arriba es el que me tira el null

```
String stringConexion = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    Connection conexion = null;
    try{
    String txtID = txtcEmpleado.getText(); //guardas el valor de tu textfield en un String
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(stringConexion, "proyasistencia2","123");
    PreparedStatement consulta = conexion.prepareStatement("UPDATE empleados SET nombre=?,apPaterno=?,apMaterno=?,departamento=? WHERE cuentaEmpleado = ?"); //tu consulta
    consulta.setString(1,txtID); //envias el dato a consultar
    ResultSet resultado = consulta.executeQuery(); //obtienes un resultado
    if (resultado.next()){  //en caso de que el id exista 
        txtNombre.setText(resultado.getString("nombre"));
            txtApaterno.setText(resultado.getString("apPaterno"));
            txtAmaterno.setText(resultado.getString("apMaterno"));
            txtDepartamento.setText(resultado.getString("departamento"));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro actualizado correctamente");
            
    }else{  //en caso de que el id no exista

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error ");

    }

}catch (SQLException e) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());

}
```

este código es el que me tira la excepción de SQL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojala alguien pudiese ayudarme. Gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Cual es la excepcion SQL que te arroja Java? Agregala porfa

Comment: Hola, ya la agregue

Comment: Aquí hay un posible error `UPDATE empleados SET nombre="+nom+"`. En SQL, las cadenas de texto van delimitadas por la comilla simple. Cuando el statement se construye queda: `SET nombre = Luis Angel`, cuando debería quedar: `SET nombre = 'Luis Angel'`. Incluye las comillas en el statement.

Comment: Otra observación. Crea nombres de variable descriptivas. Java, C#, Javascript, SQL, son lenguajes que permiten nombres de identificadores largos. Para alguien que lee el código por primera vez, el objetivo de las variables `String cve, nom, apa, ama , dep;` no será obvio a primera vista. En cambio `String cvEmpleado, nombreEmpleado, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, departamento;` es mil veces más descriptivo y lo comprendes a la primera.

Comment: En el código que te tira la excepción, qué estás haciendo? Quieres **obtener** el objeto de la base de datos? o quieres **actualizar** el objeto en la base de datos? Parece que quieres obtener el objeto, pero la sentencia dice `UPDATE`

Comment: Hola amigo, como tip en el primer caso  obtén el valor que se forma en la cadena sqlactualizar y trata de ejecutarlo directamente en la BD así te podrás percatar si se esta formando bien la cadena, para el segundo caso te marca error porque esta haciendo referencia a un valor que no se introduce en tu consulta SQL, y de igual manera en ese caso le mandas como parámetro un id para realizar búsqueda y no introduces los datos para una actualización. Como alternativa puedes utilizar un procedimiento almacenado para realizar de mejor manera estas operaciones.

Comment: El primer elenco, debe agregar una cita simple para delimitar el texto UPDATE empleados SET nombre = '"+ nom +"', apPaterno = '"+ apa +"'. Copie esta parte y péguela en otro lugar, verá que hay una simple cita dentro del SQL.

Su segundo caso, está haciendo un UPDATE y espera un resultado de ella, para obtener resultados, después de su UPDATE tiene que hacer una SELECT. Sin un SELECT, no puede hacer tener un ResultSet obteniendo información.